# How to release memory resources after django-background-task completes its execution?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I'm executing some of the long-running tasks with Django-background-tasks. Background task takes some data from DB and
process it internally which requires memory of 1 GB for each task.

The task is running in the async way.

When any task runs and completes its execution, Django-background-tasks does not release the memory after completing execution. Which causing memory issues to the Dameon pod. Any solution around deallocation of memory resources in Django-background-task?
E.g.

**Note**: resources available are fixed. so need a workaround on resource deallocation of tasks. Currently, memory gets deallocated when the pod restarts.

This is how module structure looks like.

```py
../bulk_file_operations/
├── apps.py
├── tasks.py
├── views.py
├── file_handler.py
```

**tasks.py**

```py
@background()
def my_task():
    """
    a long-running task that takes time of 20-30 mins, which includes some DB interactions.
    """
    process_data_n_download(model_queryset_object)
    pass
```

**file_handler.py**

```py
def process_data_n_download(queryset_object):
    """process this ORM object for file creation."""
    pass
```

Comment: Python is garbage collected. can you show us what exactly your function does to dig more ?

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi I have updated the code function formats and module structure in question, as functions are lengthy so updated prototypes of functions only.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running your code on `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: yes. code is running in Debug=False mode.

Comment: You will have to provide the actual code to dig further here. `django-background-tasks` just uses a ThreadPool executor. If you've modified anything other than locals in your function (which is likely if you're working with a DB) that could be why you're not seeing memory freed. This may also depend on how you're running django (e.g. using gunicorn, gevent, etc...) -- you may have some code that's not thread safe or that isn't taking care with the DB connection. So, in order to provide specific help, please show your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly free memory. What you need to do is to make sure you don't keep references to objects. They will then be garbage collected, freeing the memory.

In your case,

1. if you need large lists, you typically need to reorganize the code, typically using generators/iterators instead. That way you don't need to have the large lists in memory at all. http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/07/introduction-python-generators.html
2. Check if `django-background-tasks` app's internals if it is keeping any references. also, check your code too. You can use the `del` keyword to remove the references if any.